# How I Need to send Email Notification for picklist field value(User) when record saved

Tags: workflow

I have pick list field “Assign To" in contact object in that 3 users are there, If I am selecting any user it automatically send an email to user saying that perticlular item is assigned for you.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: Is the 'Assign To' field an Email field? If so, it should show up as an option in workflows, etc... but as Keith said, a better description of the issue might help.

Comment: If your field type is Picklist, then it will not be possible. You would need to change the picklist field to a lookup field. If you HAVE-TO-HAVE the field as a Picklist field, then you would need to create another field of type lookup(user) or Email and then populate it using a trigger. A WF Rule can then send a notification.